# Windows Moblie Chat Application Development - Where to Start?

Tags: .net, mysql, windows-mobile, xmpp

This is my final semester project. I have no knowledge of mobile application development.My operating system is Wndows7. Can anybody help me to know the following things??

1. I am asked to develop in .Net platform, So which language (whether it is ASP.net or C#.net or VB.net)i must choose?
2. What are my prerequisties to develop the application.( i downloaded - Windows moblie 6 standard SDK, .Net framework)
   3.Whether emulators will be integrated within the SDK?
   4.I have to use XMPP protocol.
   5.The back end is MYSQL
   6.File Transfer have to be integrated with inchat. But i should not use FTP for that.
   Where to begin? - This is my big question.
   What are the books i have to buy to learn these things?
   Could you people help me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. c#
2. IMHO Windows Mobile seems to be a dead platform. But of course you can still use it. But I would also look at Windows Phone 7
3. All the Mobile SDKs ship with emulators for testing and debugging
4. You don't have to, but its the best choice
5. When you use XMPP you need no additional backend database. You choose one of the existing XMPP servers and just use it. All servers have a storage for user accounts and other stuff, and of course this can be a MySQL database.
6. XMPP has extensions for file transfer which are not based on FTP, they are either p2p or pass the traffic through the XMPP server.

if you choose XMPP you can find XMPP libraries here which help you a lot with this project:
http://www.ag-software.de/

Comment: thanks alex, (2) You mean windows phone 7 SDK is better than Windows Moblie SDK .

Comment: no,I mean that current phones on the market have Windows Phone 7 as OS, not Windows Mobile.